# Tabula-py error on linux environment

Tags: python, tabula

Why do I keep getting this error "Traceback (most recent call last): File "sfctabpytrial.py", line 1, in   from tabula import read_pdf ImportError: No module named tabula" when I try to run this code:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df = read_pdf("TCP.pdf")
df # display the df contents
```

in Linux.

Comment: A few questions. Is `tabula` a package that you `pip-install`? If so, are you able to verify that it is indeed installed? Check your distribution in Linux by using `which python` in the shell. That will point you to the executable location, similar to `/usr/local/bin/python3`. From there, you can go back and find the `lib` folder (`/usr/local/lib`) which will hold the `pythonx.x` folder, and `site-packages`. Checking `site-packages` for `tabula` will show you if you have it pip installed

Comment: yes tabula was pip installed. I tried the steps in your suggestion but  I do not have access to the lib folder  " /opt/local/lib", permission was denied. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Curious that it would be in `/opt`, rather than `/usr`, since on *nix style systems, that's generally the go-to install path. I'm assuming you don't have sudo access, and `chown` may be a bad idea. You could try to `git clone` tabula's repository, and import it from there. Possibly a bit overkill if you can pip install, but a workaround nonetheless. Their repo can be found [here](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py). Just use `git clone <tabula_url>` in an empty directory where you have read-write permissions. 'wrapper.py` is the file, and `tabula` is the folder with `__init__.py`

Comment: I am really new to Linux as well as python and the system that I am working on has a lot of restrictions. Is there a quick code I can enter on the command line to see if the package/module is installed? I tried "dpkg -s tabula-py" and  the system says it was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

the tabula module (tabula-py) was located on python 3 but I was running the code on python 2.7 once I changed the version the code could be executed.